# Designing a Kalaman filter

Tags: kalman-filter

I am working on a project to monitor a water tank for energy storage. I have a large water tank, to which 10 thermometers are attached. By measuring the temperature, I can estimate the energy stored in the tank. That is quite simple, but I want to add another feature.

By sampling the amount of energy in time, I want to determine the power that is currently flowing in or out of the tank. I am measuring the energy in the tank every minute and determining the current power by comparing it to the last measurement. The direct result is very noisy (for example jumping between 2-4 kW), so I need some kind of filtering.

I started simply with averaging, which works fine,(current power is the average from last 10 measurements) but I wanted to try something a bit fancier. So I wrote a simple Kalman filter, the one described in this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZrFFg5_Sd0&list=PLX2gX-ftPVXU3oUFNATxGXY90AULiqnWT&index=5 The problem is, I guess, that this filter is designed for static measurements, and my measurement changes quite a bit. As an example, in this plot, there are 60 measurements (1 every minute) and the line is the output of the Kalman filter:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvlbD.png)

Is it possible to modify the filter to follow the actual value more accurately? Or is this just not a suitable system to filter with this kind of filter and I should use something else?

Comment: Why is the direct result so noisy? Is there a lot of error in your temperature measurements or energy-estimation calculation?

Comment: The reason is, that the tank is quite big and the temperature changes rather slowly, and the resolution of the thermometers is limited (it is about 0.2 degrees °C). So for example, if I measure every minute, the temperature only increases by 0.2 degrees on 3 thermometers, and remains the same on the rest. So for example in the first minute, the temperature rises on 4 thermometers, the next one on 3 thermometers and the next one on 5 thermometers and so on. That is why the measurement is noisy and you can see clear "levels" in the data.